# Executable script gets permission denied on Linux box

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

trying to run a script on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
$ bash MirroirHome
```

runs fine

but

```
$ ./MirroirHome
bash: ./MirroirHome: Permission denied

$ ls -l
total 32
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gerald gerald  214 nov 14 15:44 MirroirHome
```

I am the owner of the file and the permission bit is on, what is going on??

Here is the script in case it matters.

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync \
--archive \
--verbose \
--compress \
--update \
--delete \
/home/ /media/Data/MirroirHome
```

Comment: Add the executable bit ? : `$ chmod +x MirroirHome` ... Though is seems to be OK ....

Comment: 1.  add 'set -x' as the second line of the script and then run; 2. confirm that 'bash' is in fact '/bin/bash' and that perms are 'good' (i.e. -rwxr-xr-x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if the partition is mounted with the `noexec` flag on. You can verify this by running `mount`: find the partition in the output, and in the list of flags, probably there will be `noexec`.

To resolve this, remount the partition without the `noexec` flag. Or, copy the script to another partition that's already mounted without `noexec`.

Comment: That did it!!!  I had the flag "user" set for that partition in /etc/fstab, this flag in incompatible, I found out, with exec.  Removed the "user" flag, rebooted and everythig is now fine.  Allowed me to set up automatic backups via crontab.  Thanks.